# How to check current connection information on MongoDB?

Tags: connections, mongodb-3.2

Very new to MongoDB, I mean really, really new.
I want to be able to confirm my connection details when I login to the database, similar to PostgreSQL where I just run conninfo or in Oracle where I do show user and do a select from v$instance.

I can't seem to be able to find such command in Mongo? Can someone please advise if there is a way that I can get this information? The main purpose really is to be able to confirm that I am connected to the right database before doing something.

I connect like below, -u will change over time, it will change

> mongo admin -u mongoadmin -p xxxxxx

I found db.currentOp() but this list all sessions. There is also  db.hostInfo() but I am just after the hostname. I can't find one for the current user that I am login as. My version from db.version() shows 3.2.7.

In short, I just want to run one 'command' if that is at all possible, that will show, current host, database and user that I am using when I am connected to the database.

Please advise if this is possible. Thanks in advance.